# jquery - finding the name of the element I have a reference to

Tags: jquery

In code I have a reference to a DOM element, in Jquery. How do I find out it's id? It maybe counter-intuitive, but I need to know that so I can do some manipulations on another element with a similar name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).attr("id")
```

Comment: thanks, I so wished i had asked thid question 12 hours ago, when I was about to give my presentation and the prototype was busted because I couldn't find the id of my element. sucks, but this will save me at some other demo :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the id then you can use

```
$("youelementselector").attr("id");
```

and if you want elements name then

```
$("youelementselector").attr("name");
```

See **[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to a *DOM element*, you can simply access the ID with `this.id` or `element.id`.

[Here is a list of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLElement), `HTMLElement`s have.