# Finding the name of "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery - finding the name of the element I have a reference to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236028/jquery-finding-the-name-of-the-element-i-have-a-reference-to)

I have a small problem with droppables / draggables.

is it possible to get the id of a dropped div if all you have is

```
$(this)
```

coming in at the helper section. eg something like this:

```
$("#"+ place).droppable({ accept:  tile,  drop:  handler,  zIndex: 0 });
```

...

```
function handler(event, ui){ 
 $(this).css('background-image','url(pretzel-icon-clip-art.jpg)');
 $(ui.draggable).remove();  
}
```

I have several tiles dragging so differentiating between them is becoming useful.

Any help appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

Should do it.

Comment: oops, just saw this is being voted as duplicate to be closed...

Comment: Exactly. Since you have a reference to the object, you can ask it anything about itself, it's attributes or it's surrounding (or contained) elements

Comment: Which is just an expensive way of doing `this.id`.